# Ruby: Data to a file only being written / saved / visible after program terminates

Tags: ruby, multithreading, file, io

I am running a thread that does a few things.

1. It gets a float from an API
2. Appends that number into a file
3. Prints that number to the command terminal
4. Repeats

Code:

```
   price_file = File.open(price_file, "w+")

   $time = Thread.new { 

        while true
            price = Api.new.api(nil)

            price_file << price
            price_file << " "
           
            puts price

            sleep(seconds)
        end
    }
```

The prices or numbers only appear in the file after I terminate the loop or program.

I want to be able to run some functions on the numbers being added to the file while the program is still running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby usually doesn't write content into files or strings to the console immediately. Instead, it buffers output and write the output in chunks.

When you need the output immediately and do not want to wait, then there are two options:

- Close the file after writing and open it again when you have more data to write. This might be preferred in your use-case in which you want another process to read from that file at the same time. Closing the file should ensure that the file is in a consistent state.
- Or you can set `price_file.sync = true` after opening the file. When [`IO.sync=`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) is set to `true`, then all output is immediately flushed to the underlying operating system and is not buffered internally.